# angular.js select doesn't show the option value in the begining

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular.js and bootstarp - angular-ui-bootstarp. and I found a problem that when using the select, even the option is not empty, the select in the page always show nothing until you click the option list.
The first thing I tried is directly put options in the select, and make one option with ng-selected="selected", but no working

```
 <select class=" input-sm pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" ng-change="selectUserFilter()" ng-model="user_filter_key" >
  <option >All</option>
  <option ng-selected="selected">Active</option>
 </select>
```

The second thing I tried is to embedded a model with options list into the select, still not working

```
  $scope.user_options = ['All','Active'];
 <select class=" input-sm pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" ng-change="selectUserFilter()" ng-model="user_filter_key" ng-options="opt for opt in user_options">
     </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/tifur/1/edit

just set user_filter_key in yyour controler by :

```
 $scope.user_filter_key = $scope.user_options[0]
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <select class=" input-sm pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;" ng-change="selectUserFilter()" ng-model="user_filter_key" ng-options="opt for opt in user_options">
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user_options = ['All', 'Active'];


  //add this
  $scope.user_filter_key = $scope.user_options[0]



});
```

Comment: Thanks, a simple fix but helps a lot